# Inherit and modify kanban view using web kanban one2many module

Tags: odoo-13

I am trying to use the module web kanban one2many from the odoo app store with version 13 of odoo.

I find the documentation quite sparse for this module, but others seem to have it working.

I installed the module, and added the following to my module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="co7_crm_kanban_inherit">
        <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <kanban>
                <field name="order_ids"/>
                <templates>
                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                        <div>
                            <div>SOs:</div>
                            <t t-foreach="order_ids.raw_value" t-as="record">
                                <t t-esc="record.name"/>
                            </t>
                        </div>
                    </t>
                </templates>
            </kanban>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

I have confirmed the view is loaded correctly, and that it is inheriting the correct parent view. The kanban view I am attempting to modify is the crm.lead kanban view.

Unfortunately, nothing happens... None of the `order_ids` are displayed, and even the `<div>SOs:</div>` doesn't show.

I am confused as to how the templating engine is supposed to know where I want my `<div>` to go. I was expecting to have to use `<x-path>` to place my content where I wanted, but this is how everyone seems to be doing it on SO.

Basically, I just want a list of associated sales orders to appear above the "tags" on each kanban "card". What am I doing wrong?

More info:

The web one2many module is working, in chrome debugging tools I can see an HTTP request and the correct response:

```
    {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 795331297, "result": [[{"id": 21, "name": "S00020", "origin": "Modern Open Space", "client_order_ref": false, "reference": false, "state": "draft", "date_order": "2022-01-18 12:34:31", "validity_date": false, "is_expired": false, "require_signature": true, "require_payment": true, "remaining_validity_days": 0, "create_date": "2022-01-18 17:34:38", "user_id": [2, "Mitchell Admin"], "partner_id": [10, "Deco Addict"], "partner_invoice_id": [10, "Deco Addict"], "partner_shipping_id": [10, "Deco Addict"], "pricelist_id": [1, "Public Pricelist (USD)"], "currency_id": [2, "USD"], "analytic_account_id": false, "order_line": [], "invoice_count": 0, "invoice_ids": [], "invoice_status": "no", "note": "", "amount_untaxed": 0.0, "amount_by_group": [], "amount_tax": 0.0, "amount_total": 0.0, "currency_rate": 1.0, "payment_term_id": [4, "30 Days"], "fiscal_position_id": false, "company_id": [1, "YourCompany"], "team_id": [1, "Europe"], "signature": false, "signed_by": false, "signed_on": false, "commitment_date": false, "expected_date": false, "amount_undiscounted": 0.0, "type_name": "Quotation", "transaction_ids": [], "authorized_transaction_ids": [], "sale_order_template_id": false, "sale_order_option_ids": [], "tag_ids": [4], "opportunity_id": [25, "Modern Open Space"], "campaign_id": [3, "Email Campaign - Services"], "source_id": [1, "Search engine"], "medium_id": false, "activity_ids": [], "activity_state": false, "activity_user_id": false, "activity_type_id": false, "activity_date_deadline": false, "activity_summary": false, "activity_exception_decoration": false, "activity_exception_icon": false, "message_is_follower": true, "message_follower_ids": [263], "message_partner_ids": [3], "message_channel_ids": [], "message_ids": [305], "message_unread": false, "message_unread_counter": 0, "message_needaction": false, "message_needaction_counter": 0, "message_has_error": false, "message_has_error_counter": 0, "message_attachment_count": 0, "message_main_attachment_id": false, "website_message_ids": [], "message_has_sms_error": false, "access_url": "/my/orders/21", "access_token": false, "access_warning": "", "display_name": "S00020", "create_uid": [2, "Mitchell Admin"], "write_uid": [2, "Mitchell Admin"], "write_date": "2022-01-18 17:34:38", "__last_update": "2022-01-18 17:34:38"}]]}
```